# Find eigen functions corresponding to the same eigen value $1$ for the given integral equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations

Find the eigen values and eigen functions of the integral equation :
$$\phi(x)-\lambda \int_{-1}^1\cos[\pi(x-t)]\phi(t)\,dt=f(x)$$

Consider the homogeneous integral equation
\begin{align*}
\phi(x)&=\lambda \int_{-1}^1\cos[\pi(x-t)]\phi(t)\,dt\\
&=A\lambda \cos(\pi x)+B\lambda \sin(\pi x)
\end{align*}
where, $A=\int_{-1}^1\phi(t) \cos(\pi t)\,dt$ and $B=\int_{-1}^1\phi(t) \sin(\pi t)\,dt$.

Solving we get, $(1-\lambda)A=0$ and $(1-\lambda)B=0$. So $\lambda =1,1$ are the eigen values.

But I am unable to find the eigen function corresponding to the eigen value $1$.

Any help plase?

Comment: You have that practically in the equation, set $λ=1$ and get $\phi(x)=A\cos(\pi x)+B\sin(\pi x)$

Comment: @LutzLehmann Yes. Then from here can we say that $\cos(\pi x)$ and $\sin(\pi x)$ are the eigen functions ?

Comment: Yes, they span the eigenspace.